# Regular expressions of prefixes/suffixes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, regular-expressions

It is well-known that *star-free regular expressions*, which are defined by the grammar

$r::= a \mid r \cdot r \mid r \cup r \mid \neg r \mid \varepsilon \mid \emptyset$

where $a$ belongs to a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ and $\varepsilon$ is the empty string,
have their language-emptiness problem which is non-elementary (more precisely, tower-complete), being negation the "difficult case".

However, what can we say about the same problem for this kind of regular expressions?

$r::= a \mid r \cdot \Sigma^+ \mid \Sigma^+\cdot r \mid r \cup r \mid \neg r \mid\varepsilon \mid \emptyset$

Here, we still have negation, and still no Kleene star, as $\Sigma^+$ can be "rewritten" as $\neg(\emptyset \cup \varepsilon)$, but **concatenation is weakened**: in fact, $r \cdot \Sigma^+$ and $\Sigma^+\cdot r$ represent right-/left-extensions of $r$ with any (non-empty) string.

Does anybody know the complexity of this problem? Is it elementary? Do you know similar problems/connected literature?
Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: **both** left- and right-extensions must be present! Not just one of them!

Comment: Using alternating automata over finite words, it is easy to prove PSPACE membership of emptiness, if **only one** of right or left-extensions is present

Comment: **EXPSPACE-hardness** of the problem can be proved, by a reduction from domino-tiling with rows of exponential length (we encode rows by concatenating them, and add binary column counters to enforce vertical adjacency contraints).

Comment: I have tried to prove non-elementarity (tower-hardness) by encoding the nested Turing machine computations à là Meyer&Stockmeyer, but it works only at the first level (EXPSPACE-hardness). It fails to encode "movable" rulers.